# How to make bootstrap 3 tooltip work with parent div with overflow:hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="cart">
   <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="add to cart">
       <i class="fa fa-cart"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

**JQuery**:

```js
 $('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
   animated : 'fade',
   placement : 'bottom'
});
```

**CSS**:

```css
.cart{
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:10px 3px;
}
```

When I hover the cart icon, the tooltip shows, but it is not at the top of the cart box.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Fix - don't use `overflow:hidden`

Comment: if you want it top of the icon, then use palcement 'top', or pls show an image of issue

Comment: Here's a [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/a4WwQ/) of the code.  I'm really not seeing what the issue is.  @PeterJack, can you use / modify this or add a screen shot to demonstrate what the problem is.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `container` attribute so tooltip itself will be placed in parent container or event body element and it won't break even with overflow hidden because it will be positioned absolutely.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
   animated : 'fade',
   placement : 'bottom',
   container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Some users may need to adjust the z-index of .popover, too, particularly if the popover is triggered from within a modal.

Comment: If you want to specify a container in your HTML, use the attribute "data-container"

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply add data-container="body" to the tooltipped element. E.g. `<button type="submit" title="Add Record to Book Bag" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" aria-role="button"> ... </button>`

Answer (score 0):

As @Morpheus suggested - don't use `overflow:hidden`. Are you doing this as a float-clearing trick? If so, use the other clearfix hack using pseudo element. (http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Alternatively, if you must use `overflow:hidden` and you are using Tooltip v3 there is an option called `container` which is used to specify a selector to which the tooltip element will be appended.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips